# Include the CGAL shared libraries to deploy a CGAL program

Tags: dll, deployment, cmake, shared-libraries, cgal

I'm building a C++ program using CGAL, and I'm writing CMake install rules to deploy said program so that I can CPack the result and the end user doesn't have to install CGAL or any of its dependencies to use it. In order to do that, I need to include every shared library (DLLs on Windows etc) but I can't find a CMake variable that lets me do that. I searched around in the CGAL repo, but no luck. I tried using `${CGAL_LIBRARIES}` but those don't give paths, and it doesn't seem like `${CGAL_LIBRARIES_DIRS}` is a thing.

My current CMakeLists is based off the one generated by the dedicated CGAL script :

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_CMakeLists
# This is the CMake script for compiling a set of CGAL applications.

project( MeshCleaner )

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

# CGAL and its components
find_package( CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS  )

if ( NOT CGAL_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")
  return()  

endif()


# Boost and its components
find_package( Boost REQUIRED )

if ( NOT Boost_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the Boost library, and will not be compiled.")

  return()  

endif()

# include for local directory
include_directories( BEFORE include )

# include for local package


# Creating entries for target: meshCleaner
# ############################

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME}  main.cpp )

add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} )

# Link the executable to CGAL and third-party libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}   ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION . COMPONENT Libraries)

message(${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES})

if(WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_OPENMP_LIBRARIES TRUE)
    include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
endif()

include(${PROJECT_NAME}CPack)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to "fix" that issue is to use CGAL as header-only. Please check the manual. Here is [the direct link to the installation manual of CGAL-4.14, section "Header-only with CMake Configuration".](https://doc.cgal.org/4.14/Manual/installation.html#title15)

Comment: I've seen that but it's not really a possibility for me, as it causes problems on Windows (the point of me using CMake being cross-platform compatibility).

Comment: Let me know about the issue you have on Windows. It is supposed to worked well, and it is tested. And tell us which CGAL version you use.

Comment: I'm only referring to section 7.3.4 in the very link you posted. I'd rather not run into those, and I don't really want to change my project since it works like it is, with the installed version of CGAL. Is there really no way to have a CMake variable direct to a list of DLLs/SOs ? For reference, the FindOptiX.cmake file from Nvidia's shared samples source do that : https://github.com/nvpro-samples/shared_sources/blob/master/cmake/FindOptix.cmake

Comment: You should read that section 7.3.4. Do you really care that `CGAL::get_default_random()` returns a global singleton for your whole application?